# Unique rotation matrix using two axes when rotating a vector

Tags: matrices, geometry, trigonometry, 3d, rotations

I have a vector $v1$, and a rotated vector $v2$. I want to find two rotation matrices $Rx$ and $Ry$, which are rotation matrices around x-axis and y-axis, respectively, so that $Rx \times Ry \times v1 = v2$. My intuition tells me both $Rx$ and $Ry$ are unique if I restrict $\theta$, which corresponds to $Rx$ as between [-90, 90], and $\phi$, which corresponds to $Ry$ as between [0, 360]. But how am I going to find those matrices?

Make the problem simplified, let $v1=(0,0,1)$. I finally get this equation:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\sin(\phi) \\
-\sin(\theta)cos(\phi) \\
\cos(\theta)cos(\phi) \\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}.$

But I don't feel right about that. $\phi$ is determined by $x$? It's so easy to find a counterexample, e.g. $v1=(0, 0, 1), v2=(x, y, 0)$. In this case, $\phi$ should be 90 or 270.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your counterexample is not a counterexample. The vectors must have the same magnitude, so in $v_2$, $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (there are only two possible values). The rotation around the $y$ axis can take $(0,0,1)$ to $(x,0,\sqrt{1-x^2})$, which is certainly achievable because you've allowed up to $360^\circ$ rotation around the $y$ axis, and then you rotate by either $90^\circ$ or $-90^\circ$ around the $x$ axis to make $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, whichever is required. The second rotation is obviously in the interval $[-90^\circ,90^\circ]$.

Comment: In fact, $v_1=(0,0,1)$ is one of the (relatively) few values of $v_1$ for which you **cannot** create a counterexample. One way to get an actual counterexample is to set $v_2 = (1,0,0)$ and let $v_1$ be a vector for which $y\neq 0$. Another counterexample is $v_1=(0,1,0)$ where $v_2$ is any vector that has a non-zero $x$ coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation about the $x$ axis by an angle $\theta$ is given by the rotation matrix:

$ R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && c_1 && -s_1 \\ 0 && s_1 && c_1 \end{bmatrix} $

where $c_1 = \cos \theta, s_1 = \sin \theta $

And the rotation about the $y$ axis by an angle $\phi$ is given by the rotation matrix:

$R_y = \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && 0 && s_2 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ -s_2 && 0 && c_2 \end{bmatrix} $

where $c_2 = \cos(\phi), s_2 = \sin(\phi) $

So, the combined rotation is

$ R = R_x R_y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && c_1 && -s_1 \\ 0 && s_1 && c_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && 0 && s_2 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ -s_2 && 0 && c_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && 0 && s_2 \\ s_1 s_2 && c_1 && -s_1 c_2 \\ - c_1 s_2 && s_1 && c_1 c_2 \end{bmatrix} $

Now given two arbitrary unit vectors given as follows:

$v_1 = ( x_1, y_1, z_1 ) $ and $v_2 = (x_2,  y_2, z_2 ) $

where $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 = 1 = x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2 $

And you want $v_2 = R v_1 $, so

$ \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_2 && 0 && s_2 \\ s_1 s_2 && c_1 && -s_1 c_2 \\ - c_1 s_2 && s_1 && c_1 c_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{pmatrix} $

From the first component of the left and right sides of this vector equation we have

$ x_2 = c_2 x_1 + s_2 z_1 $

And this equation can be solved for $\phi$ as long as

$ | x_2 | \le \sqrt{ x_1^2 + z_1^2} $

Otherwise there is no solution.

Assuming this inequality is satisfied, then we have $\phi$ and therefore, $c_2$ and $s_2$.

The second component says

$ y_2 = s_1 s_2 x_1 + c_1 y_1 - s_1 c_2 z_1 = s_1 (s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1) + c_1 y_1 $

And this equation will have a solution if and only if

$ | y_2 | \le \sqrt{ (s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1)^2 + y_1^2 } $

And finally, from the third component, we have

$ z_2 = c_1 ( c_2 z_1 - s_2 x_1 ) + s_1 y_1 $

And it will have a solution if and only if

$ | z_2 | \le \sqrt{ (c_2 z_1 - s_2 x_1)^2 + y_1^2 } $

It can shown that the last two inequalities follow from the first one.  So only one check is necessary, namely, that  $|x_2| \le \sqrt{x_1^2+z_1^2} $.

If this inequality is satisfied, then we readily obtaine $\phi$ of $R_y$.  And then to find $\theta$ of $R_x$, solve for $c_1$ and $s_1$ from the second and third components.  These two equations can be written as the following linear system in $c_1 $ and $s_1$

$\begin{bmatrix} y_1 && s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1 \\ c_2 z_1 - s_2 x_1 && y_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ s_1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix} $

From which

$ \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ s_1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{y_1^2 + ( s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1)^2 } \begin{bmatrix} y_1 && c_2 z_1 - s_2 x_1 \\ s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1 && y_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_2 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}$

And this simplifies to

$ \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ s_1 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{y_1^2 + (s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1)^2 } \begin{bmatrix} y_1 y_2 + z_2 (c_2 z_1 - s_2 x_1) \\ (s_2 x_1 - c_2 z_1) y_2 + y_1 z_2 \end{bmatrix} $

Once we have the numerical value of $c_1$ and $s_1$, angle $\theta$ can be determined uniquely as

$ \theta = \text{atan2}(c_1, s_1) $

So, in summary, if there are solutions, we can have a single solution (this case occurs when $| x_2 | = \sqrt{ x_1^2 + z_1^2}$  .  Otherwise, there will be exactly two solutions for $\phi$ and a corresponding unique $\theta$ for each of the two $\phi$'s.

Comment: With the restriction on $\theta$ stated in the question, the condition $|x_2| \le \sqrt{x_1^2+z_1^2}$ is not sufficient to guarantee that there is a solution. I give the full conditions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not always possible. Consider for instance the situation in figure below. Rotating vector $v_1$ about $y$-axis (green) will make its endpoint to stay on the purple circle. But the transformed vector can be carried to $v_2$ after a rotation about $x$-axis (red) only if its endpoint lies on the orange circle. And that is impossible, because those two circles don't intersect.

As an extreme case, think of $v_1$ lying on the $y$-axis: $Ry$ will have no effect on it, and $Rx$ can then do its job only if $v_2$ lies in the $yz$-plane.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea of this transformation is really quite simple. The last rotation (about the $x$ axis) cannot change the $x$ coordinate, so the first rotation (around the $y$ axis) **must** set the $x$ coordinate to whatever final value it requires.

The limitation of the first rotation is that it cannot change the $y$ coordinate.
If $v_1 = ( x_1, y_1, z_1 )$,
then the vector after any rotation around the $y$ axis can only be a vector
$v' = (x', y_1, z')$ where the magnitudes of $v'$ and $v_1$ are the same.
Moreover, since the last rotation can't change the $x$ coordinate, the only way to have a solution is if $x' = x_2$, so the result of the first rotation really needs to be
$v' = (x_2, y_1, z')$.

That's why $\phi$ is determined by $x$ in your "counterexample". Under the conditions you have set up, the only way to get the desired $x$ coordinate in $v_2$ is by choosing an appropriate rotation around $y$. There are at most two choices that work within the permitted minimum and maximum rotation angles, and they are precisely the ones that (in your example) satisfy $\sin(\phi)=x$.

The general case is only a little more complicated than your example,
but we can simplify it by considering only vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ with magnitude $1$
(unit vectors), such as the vector $(0,0,1)$ that you used in your example.
Then we know that the magnitude of $v'$ also has to be $1$.
We already know two of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $v'$ by examining the coordinates of $v_1$ and $v_2$, so only $z'$ is left to determine.

The square of the magnitude of $v'$ is
$$ x_2^2 + y_1^2 + z'^2 = 1. $$
If this is solvable, it has two solutions:

$$ z' = \pm\sqrt{1 - (x_2^2 + y_1^2)}. $$

So we have a solution if and only if $x_2^2 + y_1^2 \leq 1$.
Since the conditions for setting up the problem, which put no restriction on $v_1$ and $v_2$ other than that they are both unit vectors, allow $x_2$ and $y_1$ each to be anything between $-1$ and $1$, independently of each other,
it is not guaranteed that there will be a solution.

But let's suppose that $x_2^2 + y_1^2 \leq 1$.
Then since $\phi$ has a full $360^\circ$ interval which we can choose our angle of rotation around the $y$ axis, we can certainly find an angle $\phi$ to rotate $v_1$ to either of the vectors that have the necessary $x$ coordinate,

$$
\left(x_2, y_1, \sqrt{1 - (x_2^2 + y_1^2)}\right)
\quad\text{or}\quad
\left(x_2, y_1, -\sqrt{1 - (x_2^2 + y_1^2)}\right).
$$

Now we run into the constraint on $\theta$.
As we rotate $v'$ around the $x$ axis, it traces a circle of radius
$\sqrt{1 - x_2^2}$, but you can only go $90^\circ$ in either direction along that circle according to the constraints you have defined.
If we start with $y_1 > 0$, the minimum value of $y$ that we can rotate to
is $-\sqrt{1 - (x_2^2 + y_1^2)}$.
If we start with $y_1 < 0$, the maximum value of $y$ that we can rotate to
is $\sqrt{1 - (x_2^2 + y_1^2)}$.
This is illustrated in the figure below, where the arrows labeled $v'$ are the two choices for where we can rotate $v_1$ with the first rotation
and the green sector shows all the directions either of these vectors can be rotated to.
The red sector shows unreachable vectors.

[image]

That is, the problem as stated in the question is solvable only if
$x_2^2 + y_1^2 \leq 1$ **and** at least one of the following two statements is true:

1. $y_2$ has the same sign as $y_1$.
2. $\lvert y_2\rvert \leq \sqrt{1 - (x_2^2 + y_1^2)}$.

---

There are ways to get vectors in every possible direction
using just two rotations, one by up to $360^\circ$ in one direction and one by up to $90^\circ$ in either of two directions. Consider latitudes and longitudes on the surface of the Earth as a way of specifying a vector from the center of the Earth to the surface, or a platform that can turn completely around in a horizontal plane with a telescope mounted on that platform in a way that lets the telescope be elevated or depressed $90^\circ$ above or below the horizon.

The main reasons these examples don't apply here are that in the case of latitudes and longitudes, the angles don't express motion between points;
and in the case of the telescope, one of the rotations is about a body axis rather than a spatial axis.
That is, when you turn the platform, the axis of the telescope's mount changes direction; but when you rotate your vector around the $y$ axis, the $x$ axis doesn't change direction.

You can pretend that the telescope mount doesn't need to use a body axis if we consider the $z$ axis to be the vertical axis and start with the telescope pointing along the $y$ axis. Then we can elevate or depress the telescope by up to $90^\circ$ by rotating around the $x$ axis to the desired angle above or below the horizon.
Then we can rotate around the $z$ axis to point in the exact desired direction.

And that's another odd thing about your setup. In order to use only the axes of the coordinate system in an azimuth-elevation scheme, we do the elevation rotation -- the one that is limited to $90^\circ$ up or down -- **before** we do the rotation that is allowed $360^\circ$.
You have reversed the order of rotation.
You can still point your vector $v_2$ in any direction if you start with a suitable $v_1$ -- any $v_1$ with $y=0$ will do -- but the mechanics of doing this will look rather weird if you were expecting them to be like the azimuth-elevation model.